# How to add reference in Rmarkdown in R?

Tags: reference, r-markdown, biblatex

I have tried to make auto-reference in my rmarkdown document, unfortunately, I couldn't figured out the proper way of inserting Reference. Here is my report in my [github][1] account, which I put as a links all my references.

I have already installed bibtex.

My Rmarkdown header is:

```
title: "Case Study - Bellabeat Fitness App Data Analysis in R"
author: "Mohamed Ibrahim Abdilaahi"
date: '`Sys.Date()`'
output: 
  html_html:
    numer_sections: true
    toc: true
bibliography: reference.bib
```

I have also created reference file saved as .bib

Here is my syntax error:

```
Error in eval(xfun::parse_only(name)) : object 'html_html' not found
Calls: <Anonymous> ... create_output_format -> create_output_format_function -> eval -> eval
Execution halted
```

I am in desperate need for your help, this will also help me my ongoing real projects.
[1]: https://github.com/Moheid/fitbit_repo

Comment: I don't think that there's an output `html_html`. However, if you were to use one of the bookdown outputs, there are books for your guidance. [Check this out](https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/bibliography.html).